# .Net MVC dynamic radio button not binding correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a situation that I need a pair of eyes on. I think it has to do with the loop, but for some reason no matter what radio button selected, the last one is always saved to the db/populated. Any ideas?

```
@foreach (var l in collection.LineItems)
     {
                        var lIndex = collection.LineItems.IndexOf(l);
                        var ownerId = Model.Splits[collectionIndex].LineItems[lIndex].ownerId;
            var owners = new SelectList(Model.Owners.OrderBy(m => m.Text), "Value", "Text", ownerId);
                        var ownerName = string.Format("Splits[{0}].LineItems[{1}].ownerId", collectionIndex, lIndex);
                        var percentName = string.Format("Splits[{0}].LineItems[{1}].Percentage", collectionIndex, lIndex);
                        <tr class="split-l btn-group-parent">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Splits[collectionIndex].LineItems[lIndex].Id)
                            <input type="hidden" name="Splits[@collectionIndex].LineItems.Index" value="@lIndex" />
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Splits[collectionIndex].LineItems[lIndex].ownerId, owners, "Select One" })

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Splits[collectionIndex].LineItems[lIndex].Percentage)%

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (collection.PrimaryIndex == lIndex){
                                    <input name="Splits[@collectionIndex].PrimaryIndex" type="radio" value="@lIndex" checked="checked" />
                                } else {
                                    <input name="Splits[@collectionIndex].PrimaryIndex" type="radio"  value="@lIndex" />
                                }
                            </td>
```

Comment: There's just one radio button here!

Comment: the foreach loop iterates over a dynamic number. For example, if there is just one, it's fine, but 2, 3, etc, always selects the last one.

Comment: Can you provide the generated html code too?